# OutOfMemoryException reading response stream

Tags: c#, memory-management, file-io, out-of-memory

What could be causing an out of memory exception in the code below?  My program was running for a few hours and then died. The code only sends/receives a very small amount of data each time, so there are no huge files or strings going over the wire or coming back.   The code sends and receives from the server every 3 seconds or so.

```
private void Read()
{
    string postData = "Name=John"
    using (HttpWebResponse response = SendRequest(new Uri(@"someWebSitehere"), postData))
    {
         Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
         responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();　　IT THROWS OUT OF MEMORY HERE
     　   stream.Close();
    ｝
}

private HttpWebResponse SendRequest(Uri uri, string postData)
{
    lock (SendRequestLock)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        req.Proxy = null;
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        // Set the content type of the data being posted.
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Set the content length of the string being posted.
        req.ContentLength = byte1.Length;

        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
        using (Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
        }
        return (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: What part triggers the OOM exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to dispose of the IDisposable classes `Stream` and `StreamReader`:

```
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) 
    {
        responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();　　//IT THROWS OUT OF MEMORY HERE
    }
}
```

Classes that implement `IDisposable` generally have external resources that they will hang onto unless you call `Dispose()` (or, same thing, put it inside a `using` block).  It's likely that those classes are leaking memory each time your block of code runs, hence the "out of memory" exception after some time.

It's worthwhile reading [MSDN's notes on IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Comment: this ended up being the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked Content-Length of the response. Maybe it is very huge. In this case you should read response stream part by part

Comment: I have not checked it exactly.  What is considered a good size to start reading part by part?

Comment: It depends on what do you do with a server response.

Comment: I get text back and parse it.

Comment: In this case you can try to refactore you parser to take a Stream as input parameter. In some case this even better than parsing a string.

Comment: I will keep that in mind.  The response is only 120 bytes usually so I probably won't have to do it.